# Drawing a 3D Volume in TIKZ knowing his sections

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, 3d

I'm basically a beginner using TIKZ and I need your help to draw a volume with these features:

Domain: [0;4]

Basis of the volume (on the x-axis): it is the function f(x)=cos(x/2)+1/2 in the domain.

Sections with perpendicular planes to the x-axis: they are given by the function S(x)=3sin(πx/4)

Can you help me managing to provide a code able to create a 3D volume with these features?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Nothing... As I said, I'm a beginner, and I can't do something so complex. For this reason, I was hoping that someone really expert and fast in coding could do that for me

Comment: If you could provide a sketch that may give people a better starting point

Comment: Ok, beginner or not any effort on your part increases the chances of effort on our part. I would consider myself a beginner since I've only been using LaTeX for a few months but there is always documentation available (e.g. tikz manual) to help me get started with something complicated, leaving the forums like this for when I get truly stuck.